# BroadCast finished but the timer continue working

Tags: ios, swift

I stop the braodcast in `SampleHandler.m` use method: `[self finishBroadcastWithError:error]` , but the timer of broadcast continue working.

[![ [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvxNy.png][1]][1]

How did this happen?

Comment: HI where we can read the source code of `SampleHandler.m` ? it is really a Swift project or Objective-C ?

Comment: when you add new target of Broadcast Upload Extension ,Xcode will automatic creates 'SampleHandler.m' and 'SampleHandler.h'

Comment: You can find them in you project catalog..